# Select Cell within a range that has a maximum value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to select a cell in Excel VBA 2007

Example in row 2, cells A through H have some numbers but cell B2 has the highest value. is there a formula that I could use to get the address of  the cell B2 ?

Based on this, is there a way I could use a variable to select a Range(":") ?

I am a newbie to VBA so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A2:H2,MATCH(MAX(A2:H2),A2:H2,0)))
```

EDIT.

```
Sub max_value_address()
Dim i As Long
i = 2
'This example assigns to A1 cell the address of max value in the range a2:h2
Range("a1").Formula = "=CELL(""Address"",INDEX(A" & i & ":H" & i & ",MATCH(MAX(A" & i & ":H" & i & "),A" & i & ":H" & i & ",0)))"
End Sub
```

EDIT 2.
This version is a little bit more concise.

```
Sub max_value_address()
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
i = 2
str = "a" & i & ":h" & i 'assign to str a2:h2
Range("a1").Formula = "=CELL(""address"",INDEX(" & str & ",MATCH(MAX(" & str & ")," & str & ",0)))"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1! I really like when someone finds a more elegant Excel way to do these simple things. I'll horrible with Excel formulas :D

Comment: Thanks Tiago. :) @zack: if you don't need $ symbols simply add replace() function to my formula.

Comment: thanks Nick..this formula works if I put it inside a cell in excel but does not work if try to use a variable = "your formula here" in the VB editor..does not compile?? anything Im doing wrong here?? also can I use something like Range("E[row_variable]:M[row_variable]") to select a range?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you to reach your goal. Let us know if it's unclear.

```
Sub GetHigherValueCellAddress()

    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim oRange As Excel.Range
    Dim vPrevValue As Variant
    Dim sAddress As String

    Set oRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:C2")

    For Each oCell In oRange

        If oCell.Value > vPrevValue Then

            sAddress = oCell.Address
            vPrevValue = oCell.Value

        End If

    Next oCell

    MsgBox sAddress

End Sub
```